# How can I save data from one DB to another DB using OSB?

Tags: osb

I am new in OSB. I have a demo project. Where I need some modification.

I have a database in Oracle from where I fetch some data using db pooling. After than I run a loop and assign the specific field in a variable. I have also a business service where I save the data.

Now my question is how can I save those data that I have assigned in variable into another database?

As I am new in OSB so I am confused my question is perfect enough or not. Please help me in this regard..

Answer (score 1):

You need use a DB Adapter to insert/update records in the target DB, which you'd call form a routing stage. You can also have a previous stage where you modify the values fetched from the source DB if needed
You can find an example in http://svgonugu.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/database-polling-in-osb/

Answer (score 0):

step 1 ) You need to configure the DB Adapter as suggested in above reply.
Step 2) Use replace to transform your data stored in your variable, so that it can be accepted as request by business service  of DB adapter.